# How to change default auth password and username in laravel 5.5.28

Tags: php, rest, laravel-5, oauth, controller

I am using the auto generated auth setup for logging in and registering etc. I've got the register working but haven't been able to get the log in to work.

By default when I run it I get this error

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'email' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `consumers` where `email` = jermayne21@gmail.com limit 1)
```

Which is understandable, my email column in my db is `con_email` and my password column is `con_password`

I updated my `LoginController.php` to change the `email` and `password` attributes to the columns noted above.

**LoginController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use App\User;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }
    public function username()
    {
      return 'con_email';
    }

    public function getAuthPassword()
    {
      return $this->con_password;
    }
}
```

**User.php (for reference)**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
    protected $table = 'consumers';
    protected $primaryKey = 'con_id';


    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [ 'con_id', 'con_fname', 'con_lname', 'con_email', 'con_password', 'total_earned'];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'con_password', 'remember_token',
    ];

}
```

**login.blade.php (which I thought I didn't need to change please correct me if I'm wrong)**

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Login</div>

                <div class="panel-body">
                    <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
                        {{ csrf_field() }}

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label for="email" class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail Address</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autofocus>

                                @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 control-label">Password</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" required>

                                @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                                <div class="checkbox">
                                    <label>
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="remember" {{ old('remember') ? 'checked' : '' }}> Remember Me
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    Login
                                </button>

                                <a class="btn btn-link" href="{{ route('password.request') }}">
                                    Forgot Your Password?
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Once making the changes from the default code I no longer get an error. when I sign in it just reloads to the login screen without any validation errors (but seems as if it was almost a wrong info BUT it isn't the wrong login info.

**questions I have pertaining to other answers for similar problems I've found**
I don't have an `AuthController.php` but I have read many answers that state to override it in that file. when I ran `php artisan make:auth` it auto generated `LoginController.php`, `ForgotPasswordController.php`, `RegisterController.php`and `ResetPasswordController.php` Is this a recent update in laravel 5.5 (or maybe was done in 5.2 from what I read). I get the same current error in all my Controllers so I thought maybe `AuthController.php` was changed to the 4 separate controllers above.

Answer (score 2):

**for laravel5.5**

app/Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginController.php  - added function `username()`

```
<?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

    class LoginController extends Controller
    {
        /*
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        | Login Controller
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        |
        | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
        | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
        | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
        |
        */

        use AuthenticatesUsers;

        /**
         * Where to redirect users after login.
         *
         * @var string
         */
        protected $redirectTo = '/home';

        /**
         * Create a new controller instance.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
        }

        /**
         * Get the login username to be used by the controller.
         *
         * @return string
         */
        public function username()
        {
            return 'con_email';
        }

    }
```

Model  app/User.php  -  added function getAuthPassword()

```
<?php

    namespace App;

    use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

    class User extends Authenticatable
    {
        use Notifiable;

        /**
         * The attributes that are mass assignable.
         *
         * @var array
         */
        protected $fillable = [
            'name', 'con_email', 'con_password',
        ];

        /**
         * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
         *
         * @var array
         */
        protected $hidden = [
            'con_password', 'remember_token',
        ];


        /**
         * Get the password for the user.
         *
         * @return string
        */

        public function getAuthPassword()
        {
            return $this->attributes['con_password'];
        }
    }
```

View page login.blade.php  -  changed field name `email` to `con_email`

```
@extends('layouts.app')

    @section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">Login</div>

                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
                            {{ csrf_field() }}

                            <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('con_email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                                <label for="con_email" class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail Address</label>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input id="con_email" type="email" class="form-control" name="con_email" value="{{ old('con_email') }}" required autofocus>

                                    @if ($errors->has('con_email'))
                                        <span class="help-block">
                                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('con_email') }}</strong>
                                        </span>
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                                <label for="password" class="col-md-4 control-label">Password</label>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" required>

                                    @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                        <span class="help-block">
                                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                        </span>
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                                    <div class="checkbox">
                                        <label>
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="remember" {{ old('remember') ? 'checked' : '' }}> Remember Me
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-4">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                        Login
                                    </button>

                                    <a class="btn btn-link" href="{{ route('password.request') }}">
                                        Forgot Your Password?
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    @endsection
```

**for laravel 5.2**

You have to override `postLogin()` function in your `Auth/AuthController.php`

```
/**
 * Handle a login request to the application.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function postLogin(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'email' => 'required|email', 'password' => 'required',
    ]);

    $credentials['con_email'] = $request->input('email');
    $credentials['con_password'] = $request->input('password');

    if ($this->auth->attempt($credentials, $request->has('remember')))
    {
        return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
    }

    return redirect($this->loginPath())
        ->withInput($request->only('email', 'remember'))
        ->withErrors([
            'email' => $this->getFailedLoginMessage(),
        ]);
}
```

Comment: I don't have an `Auth/AuthController.php` should It have auto generated one? in the `Auth` Directory `ForgotPasswordController.php`, `LoginController.php`, `RegisterController.php` , `ResetPasswordController.php`

Comment: Would this go in my `LoginController.php` and would I have to alter my `login.blade.php` in order for it to work?